# PHP exec and header redirect

Tags: php, linux, exec

I have a long running PHP script that i want to be executed in background on server after a user action. and the user should be redirected to other page while command should be running in background.
Below is the code

```
$command = exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php');
header("Location: /main.php?action=welcome");
```

The above script is running fine, but page does not redirected until     **`$command = exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php');`** is executed.

I want that user should be immediately redirected to the welcome page.

Is there any other way to achieve this task.
The other idea is that that     $command = exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php'); should be executed on welcome page, but welcome page HTML is shown after the command has executed. command takes about 5,6 minutes and this time page does not redirects.

I am On Cent os Linux with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this instead:

```
$result = shell_exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

PS: Note that this is redirecting stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` If you want to capture output then use:

```
$result = shell_exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php > /tmp/script.our 2>&1 &');
```

Alternatively use this PHP function to run any Unix command in background:

```
//Run linux command in background and return the PID created by the OS
function run_in_background($Command, $Priority = 0) {
    if($Priority)
        $PID = shell_exec("nohup nice -n $Priority $Command > /dev/null & echo $!");
    else
        $PID = shell_exec("nohup $Command > /dev/null & echo $!");
    return($PID);
}
```

Courtesy: A comment posted on http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the `exec()` manual page of PHP:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

So let's do that, using `2>&1` (basically 2 is `stderr` and 1 is `stdout`, so what this means is "*redirect all stderr messages to stdout*"):

```
shell_exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php 2>&1');
```

or if you want to know what it outputs:

```
shell_exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php 2>&1 > output.log');
```

Comment: And how can i pass argument to mylongrunningscript.php like mylongrunningscript.php&uid=12

Comment: @Asghar You'd need to read stdin for that (check up on `$_SERVER["argv"]`), as `GET` parameters is something that only the HTTP protocol uses. You can take use of the HTTP protocol, by doing something like `curl http://mywebsite.com/mylongrunningscript.php?my&get&params=here 2>&1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Send the script output to /dev/null and the exec function will return immediately

```
$command = exec('php -q /mylongrunningscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1');
```